# error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method DataLength

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I have a quick question here.
using EF6 model first.

```
var db = new MyEntities(GetEntityConnectionString());

ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
ObjectSet<DOCUMENT> objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<DOCUMENT>();
var results = objectSet.Where("SqlServer.DATALENGTH(it.BINARYCONTENT)>50000");
Assert.IsTrue(results.ToList().Count == 9);

var results2 = objectSet.Where(doc=>System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DataLength( doc.BINARYCONTENT)>50000);
Assert.IsTrue(results2.ToList().Count == 9);

var results3 = db.DOCUMENTS.Where(doc => System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DataLength(doc.BINARYCONTENT) > 50000);
Assert.IsTrue(results3.ToList().Count == 9);
```

The first assert succeeds, so why do I get the following exception when results2 and results 3 are executed?

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DataLength(Byte[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there any way to get the other asserts to succeed?

Comment: It's been almost a week now.
I'm still interested to hear suggestions, no matter how old this question gets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is that I'm using the wrong function.

instead of

```
System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DataLength
```

I should be using

```
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.DataLength
```

located within EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Comment: I was deceived by the similarity of the namespaces too, thanks for pointing out this suble difference! Probably saved me a couple of hours!

Comment: This could also be simplified to SqlFunctions.DataLength if the the proper library is imported.

Comment: I am using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.DataLength and still getting the same error...

Answer (score -1):

EF does not know how to convert a C# method to SQL code.

If you change to this it should work:
(Note that I added ".ToList()")

```
var results2 = objectSet.ToList().Where(doc=>System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DataLength( doc.BINARYCONTENT)>50000);
Assert.IsTrue(results2.ToList().Count == 9);

var results3 = db.DOCUMENTS.ToList().Where(doc => System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DataLength(doc.BINARYCONTENT) > 50000);
Assert.IsTrue(results3.ToList().Count == 9);
```

When you declare a variable as an EF Query it is not actually ran until the first time it is enumerated. Enumerating it to a list before you run the where clause on it causes your Where condition to be run on the CLR objects instead of EF trying to run as part the db query.

Comment: not according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496301/how-to-get-a-byte-array-length-using-linq-to-entities

even msdn says "This function is translated to a corresponding function in the database" see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466174(v=vs.110).aspx

since DataLength is an EDM function it should translate to an SQL function.

your answer means that the entire set of data would be loaded into memory then filtered there.

this should be executed as a single filtering query.

see also:
http://www.nilzorblog.com/2011/08/linq2ef-pitfall-using-length-property.html