# Byte array empty check in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 2 models:

```
class User
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  virtual HashSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

class Book
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
  int UserId { get; set; }
  byte[] CoverImage { get; set; }
  virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

and a ModelView that contains the User, and fields from its newest Book:

```
class UserViewModel
    {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    string LatestBookName { get; set; }    
    bool hasCoverImage  { get; set; }
    }
```

I am having some trouble filling the bool attribute from the data returned from database. Getting the Users and their Books is simple, but casting to the viewModel is proving harder.

```
var usersAndBooks = dbContext.Users.Include(Books); // pseudocode here, but the real thing works
```

Here is where I need help:

```
    var viewModel = usersAndBook.Select(u => new UserViewModel()
        {
           Id = u.Id,
           Name = u.Name,
           LatestBookName = u.Books.Count > 0 && u.Books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).FirstOrDefault().Name, //works OK

          //neither of these work:

           //hasCoverImage = u.Books.Count > 0 && c.Books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).First().CoverImage.Any()             
           //hasCoverImage = u.Books.Count > 0 && c.Books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).First().CoverImage.Length > 0
        }
```

I've tried to set the hasImage value by looking at the byte array, but get runtime errors :

> "DbIsEmptyExpression requires a collection argument.\r\nParameter
>   name: argument"

for the `.Any(`)

> "The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayLength' is not supported in LINQ
>   to Entities."

for the `.Length > 0`

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault().Name` sounds dangerous (Property LatestBookName)

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to test. This is a simplification of what I am doing, so I left some null check out. These are not the issues I want to solve.

Comment: @fubo The byte array is never null, just empty if not used.

Comment: @Console `u.Books.Count > 0 && u.Books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).FirstOrDefault().Name` shouldn't compile but `u.Books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).FirstOrDefault().Name` is safe. Remember what gets executed on the client and what gets translated to SQL. This will get translated in such a way that the `Name` access just results in `null` if no `Book` object is found.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: [http://www.nilzorblog.com](http://www.nilzorblog.com/2011/08/linq2ef-pitfall-using-length-property.html)

and here: [StackOverflow post answered by @Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496301/how-to-get-a-byte-array-length-using-linq-to-entities)

This works:

```
var viewModel = usersAndBook.Select(u => new UserViewModel()
        {
           Id = u.Id,
           Name = u.Name,
           LatestBookName = u.Books.Count > 0 
                && u.Books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).FirstOrDefault().Name, 

           //this does work:
           hasCoverImage = u.Books.Count > 0 
                 && SqlFunctions.DataLength
                (c.Books.OrderByDescending(b => b.Id).First().CoverImage) > 0
        }
```

You will need to reference using `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;`